# How to check for a null value in shell

Tags: string, shell, if-statement

I have a variable(which is a string) which can have two values:
(1)variable = null
(2)variable = "some string value"

Now I have to apply a condition like:

if (variable is equal to null) then
execute step 1 
else execute step 2.

This script will be run in jenkins and actual value of variable will be replaced in the script in jenkins.

but my variable has just two values either null or some string "value"...but when script runs it replaces the values so when variable gets replaced it treats null also as a string..and so when i use -n it executes only the if part.....eg...if[-n variable -ge 1]..so when script runs...it gets replaced like this..[if -n null -ge 1] and it return true..which it shouldn't ..how to solve this

How do we check it in shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of unix test to check whether a string is empty or not.

```
 [ -z $var ] && echo empty || echo non empty # -z returns true on empty string
 [ -n $var ] && echo non empty || echo empty # -n returns true on non empty string.
```

Find mode details about test command on [link](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/test.htm) or any other better site. Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct but for OP an if-statement would be easier to read and implement. Also you can suggest `man test`.

Comment: but my variable has just two values either null or some string "value"...but when script runs it replaces the values so when variable gets replaced it treats null also as a string..and so when i use -n it executes only the if part.....eg...if[-n variable -ge 1]..so when script runs...it gets replaced like this..[if -n null -ge 1] and it return true..which it shouldnt ..how to solve this

Comment: There are some classic way to do check for empty string ( there are other better ways though ). Use [ "X${var}" = "X"  ] && echo var is empty

Comment: @WalterA, thanks for the comments. Will try to make more readable and added resources on my next opportunities

Comment: On AIX my ksh script had an error when testing an empty `var`, better is `[ -z "$var" ]`. I am wondering what is easiest for others: your notation, writing with the keyword `if` or testing verbose with `test -z "${var}"&& ...`.

Comment: @gulshankumar Quoting your var can make a difference. And you are testing like it is a number, not a string. You can test the length of a var with `${#var}`.